# How can I fix vc-annotate colouring?

Tags: faces, version-control

When I try to view the annotated text / code I can barely read it. Is there a way of changing the colouring or disabling it? See below.

[image]

Comment: See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21672/how-can-i-find-out-what-face-i-need-to-change-in-the-mode-line, https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19286/how-to-change-face-in-particular-theme-locally and try looking up many other SE answers using f.i. "change face" or "which face" search terms.

Comment: Are you running in the terminal or a GUI?

Comment: @Y.E. Thank you!! This got me the fix!

Comment: @Lindydancer terminal, but I've been able to fix it based on the comments provided :)

Answer (score 1):

First I suggest to customize `vc-annotate-background-mode`. If this doesn't help, you could try more fine-grained customization with `vc-annotate-color-map`. There are also other options for customization of vc-annotate colouring in `customize-group vc`.